# Add language resources in android apk application

Tags: android, android-resources

Well I have a single language android application that I translated strings in **res/values/strings.xml** to make it multi language application. I made for instance **values-fr/strings.xml**, **values-es/strings.xml** ...
When compiling my application, I get this error 
mayapp/res/values-fr/strings.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: XML declaration not well-formed
mayapp/res/values-es/strings.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: XML declaration not well-formed

How to solve this problem.
I need your help since I'am new in android development.

Comment: Show us the XML files which cause the error

Comment: Yeah the error is pretty clear.  Look at your strings.xml file int values-es and something is wrong - likely a missed ", end tag or xml header.

Comment: remove these xml files and try to build with only values/strings.xml , if app can build without error , copy content of string.xml into values-es/string.xml .

Comment: post values-es/strings.xml file. It should be an error in the first line..

Comment: Well, I made some modification in the values-fr/strings and I found this behavior

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

     <string name="app_name">Répondeur</string>
    
</resources>
That show me the error. and when I change **Répondeur** to Repondeur I have no problem.
how to solve this ?

Comment: I tried to copy values/strings content in values-fr/strings and I have no problem! I think the problem is related to special caracters

Comment: <string name="app_name">R&#233;pondeur</string> 

use R&#233; for é.

Answer (score 0):

use numerical code for special character:
    `<string name="app_name">R&#233;pondeur</string>`

Comment: Well I found the solution ! I changed codage type to  iso-8859-1 and it works fine ! thanks for all